# WPF PieChart filling

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I´ve got the following code:

```
private void LoadPieChartData()
{
    LinkedList<String> kostenstellen = rep.GetKostenstellen();

    for (int i = 0; i < kostenstellen.Count; i++)
    {
        ((ColumnSeries)PieChart.Series[i]).ItemsSource = new KeyValuePair<string, double>[]{
           new KeyValuePair<string,double>(kostenstellen.ElementAt(i), i+1)
           };
        }
    }
}
```

My Xaml looks like this:

```
<DVC:Chart HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="625,44,0,0" Name="PieChart" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="276" Width="256" > 
    <DVC:Chart.Series>
        <DVC:PieSeries Title="FirstPiece" ItemsSource="{Binding LoadPieChartData}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
        <DVC:PieSeries Title="SecondPiece" ItemsSource="{Binding LoadPieChartData}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
    </DVC:Chart.Series>
</DVC:Chart>
```

My problem is, that the i in the for-loop can be raise up to about 20. So, I would need about 20 PieSeries, to create them dynamic isn´t possible as I know.
How can I manage that?

Comment: Do you really want different series or are you just trying to display a chart with up to 20 segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is simply display a pie chart with several segments, all you have to do is bind a collection to a single `PieSeries`'s `ItemsSource` property:

```
<DVC:Chart Name="PieChart">
    <DVC:Chart.Series>
        <DVC:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding LoadPieChartData}" 
                       IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" 
                       DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" />
    </DVC:Chart.Series>
</DVC:Chart>
```

I used the following property:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,int>> LoadPieChartData
{
    get
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Item " + i, i);
        }
    }
}
```

And I get the following chart:

[image]

Comment: Ok, now I tried it, but it doesn´t work.
I put the Property in the Code-behind File but if I run the application, the chart doesn´t show anything...

Comment: @user896692 your DataContext is probably not set correctly, so your program doesn't know where to look for the property you bound. If the property is part of the window that hosts the chart, you can try adding something like `this.DataContext = this` in the window's constructor

Comment: Do you know how I can update the chart, when my list changes?

Comment: If you want your updates to be automatically reflected in your UI, you should look into [`ObservableCollection`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) and/or implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)